# How to define CAST to float in OpenSQL?

Tags: floating-point, abap, opensql

I try to write a select statement with CAST, but I do not know how to put in the float value.

This does not work:

```
SELECT
  field1, field2,
  CAST( field3 AS FLTP ) * CAST( '0.03' AS FLTP )  AS out2  
FROM table1
INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_table1).
```

I get this error message: `CASTs to a numeric type are not allowed for '0.03' (the type is incorrect)`, so I guess anything in quotes are assumed to be text.

I found this workaround:

```
DATA: lv_discount TYPE f VALUE '0.03'.

SELECT
  field1, field2,
  CAST( field3 AS FLTP ) * CAST( @lv_flt AS FLTP ) AS out1
FROM table1
INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_table1).
```

How can I do it without this workaround?

Comment: I'd use a constant rather than a variable, but other than that - why the cast in the first place?

Comment: @vwegert field3 is type CURR, if I just try to multiply it without casting I get this error message:  `"Only elementary arithmetic types can be used in arithmetic expressions. The type select list. The type of '0.03' is invalid."`

Comment: Let me rephrase that - Why do you want to do this in OpenSQL in the first place? 0.03 looks like the classic "magic number" to me, and to determine a "discount", I'd use something like BRF+, cause, you know - these things keep changing all the time...

Comment: @vwegert, now I understand. It came up during CDS exercises that anything you can do with CDS, you can do with OpenSQL (except Union). So the example is completely artificial, this is not how I would do this in production either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ABAP **doesn't support** decimal points in numeric literals, and they should be specified in character literals, as proposed [here](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/abenuntyped_number_literals.htm).
 
The pitfall is that `CAST` operator doesn't support character literals as its [syntax help](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/abensql_cast.htm) says:

> For the operand *operand*, columns *col* of database tables or views
>   plus host variables *dobj* and **literals of all numeric types except
>   decimal floating point numbers are possible**.

Possible workaround could be following:

```
SELECT matnr, menge,
  CAST( menge AS FLTP ) * CAST( 3 AS FLTP ) / CAST( 100 AS FLTP ) AS out2
FROM mseg
INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_table1).
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet a better alternative is to use ABAP expressions inside Open SQL

```
   SELECT
      field1, field2,
      CAST( field3 AS FLTP ) * @( conv f( '0.03' ) ) AS out1
    FROM table1
    INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_table1).
```